# Nullable Child Objects in LINQ

Tags: linq, null

As Cognate and Birth are nullable, this gives me a warning about that.

Is there any way to formulate this query as excluding the Cognate if Birth is NULL?

I wanted to use ?? in this query, but doesn't seem as if it allows that;)

```
        bookings = bookings
                .Where(x =>
                       x.Cognate.Birth.Year == Δ.Birth.Year &&
                       x.Cognate.Birth.Month == Δ.Birth.Month &&
                       x.Cognate.Birth.Day == Δ.Birth.Day
        ).ToList();
```

EDIT: Thanks for answers, but I'm a bit stumped if I do like this:

```
     bookings = bookings
                .Where(x =>
                       x.Cognate != null &&
                       x.Cognate.Birth != null &&
                       x.Cognate.Birth.Year == Δ.Birth.Year &&
                       x.Cognate.Birth.Month == Δ.Birth.Month &&
                       x.Cognate.Birth.Day == Δ.Birth.Day
        ).ToList();
```

Then I get a warning:

```
Warning CS8073 The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'DateTime' is never equal to 'null' of type 'DateTime?'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the query to exclude the `Cognate` property if its `Birth` property is null by using the null-conditional operator (?.).

So your code would look like this:

```
bookings = bookings
    .Where(x => x.Cognate?.Birth != null && 
                x.Cognate.Birth.Year == Δ.Birth.Year && 
                x.Cognate.Birth.Month == Δ.Birth.Month && 
                x.Cognate.Birth.Day == Δ.Birth.Day)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Right, of course;). Thanks, but why a question mark after Cognate; wouldn't that be a null-conditional operator, but that doesn't have to be captured; it just nulls the whole expression?;)

Comment: This is equivalent to: x.Cognate!=null && x.Cognate.Birth != null && the rest...